# Add default value only to new rows

Tags: postgresql

I want to add a new column that is `NULL` for existing rows, but has default value for new rows.

This:

```sql
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN bar timestamp NULL DEFAULT clock_timestamp();
```

Won't work, because it would add default value to existing rows.

This would work:

```sql
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN bar timestamp NULL;
ALTER TABLE foo ALTER bar SET DEFAULT clock_timestamp();
```

but I need to run 2 queries. Is it possible to do in 1 query?

Comment: What is the problem with using 2 queries?

Answer (score 2):

Some actions of ALTER TABLE can be combined into one statement, and these two are among them.

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN bar timestamp NULL, ALTER bar SET DEFAULT clock_timestamp();
```

Since neither of these requires a table rewrite, combining them doesn't do anything that couldn't be done just as well as doing both in one transaction.  But nonetheless it is possible.